# Redirecting category link to first child post

Tags: categories, redirect

I am trying to redirect the category link to the first child post. I am using following code in `category.php`. This redirects, but link doesn't go to first child post. How can I redirect to the first child post, in ASC order by date?

```
/*
 Category Template:
 Template URI: 
 Description: 
 */
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post->ID ) );
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are much too late in the page load sequence to redirect. You need to redirect before headers are sent to the browser. The `template_redirect` hook should be a pretty good option:

```
function redirect_cat_wpse_207298() {
  if (is_category()) {
    global $post;
    wp_safe_redirect(get_permalink($post->ID));
    die;
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect','redirect_cat_wpse_207298');
```

Comment: hi, this doesn't work.

Comment: Where did you put the code? It works fine when I test it.

Comment: sorry, I mistakenly added this to category.php, in functions.php working but this goes to newest child post not the oldest first post? how can I do that in ASC order?

Comment: To get the oldest you would need to use `pre_get_posts` to change the `order` argument for the archive.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `get_posts()` to refine what you are looking for/where you want to be redirected.

See [the Codex for the general use of `get_posts()` and its parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and you could use this (untested, hope it works) for your redirect:

```
<?php
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 1);
$postslist = get_posts($args);
foreach ($postslist as $post) :
  setup_postdata($post);
  wp_redirect(the_permalink());
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I've tested this, but doesn't work.

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: I've added this to category.php but not redirecting?

Comment: Ah, have a look at what @s_ha_dum wrote above. Your <code>category.php</code> runs too late, the redirect needs to be made much earlier. You could probably combine my code with his, for ordering and getting the first post...